# Converting date from text to number format

Tags: excel

Im trying to convert dates from text formats such as

Apr 10, 2020

Mar 11, 2020

I've tried using the =DateValue formula but it returns an error, and imagine thats because the full month isn't written out and possibly because its not in the right format

Can anyone help :)

Comment: I tested `DATEVALUE` formula and it returned correct date so I could not reproduce the behavior. What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your format is always consistent (`MMM DD, YYYY`) you can use the `DATE` function in combination with a `VLOOKUP`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, & `MID` for the inputs:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3),D2:E13,2,0),MID(A2,5,2))
```

---

[image]

*There may be a better way to do this, I just don't know any function that recognizes abbreviated months other than `datevalue` hence the conversion with `vlookup` here*

Answer (score 0):

Just Click the format of the cell/column to date.

[image: Excel sample image]

Comment: I believe the input is in actual text format meaning this won't work

Comment: try  =Datevalue(A1) my date text is in A1 cell this works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure custom date formats, like this:

```
[$-en-US]MMM TT, JJJJ
```

[image]